# are there any chrome extension API to set focus in the web page content?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When the chrome address bar is focused, calling element.focus() in the web page cannot steal the focus from the address bar

How can I blur the address bar and set focus to the element in the web page? any chrome extension API can do that?

Thanks.